# Ordering of last two boxes!

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, combinations

Say that you have 6 boxes. All these boxes are uniform in all ways, except one. Which is colour. From this, we can see that 2 are red boxes, 2 are pink boxes, and 2 are black boxes? How would you find the probability that the last two boxes in all combinations possible are pink?

I did something like this:

Firstly, we know that there are 2 boxes of each type initially. Thus we have
\begin{align}
\frac{6!}{2! \times 2! \times 2!}
\end{align}
(we define this as A)

Secondly, we know that the last 2 balls are pink. Now, we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{4!}{2! \times 2! }
\end{align}

(we define this as B)

Thus, the probability is P = A/B. But I feel as if this is wrong as this looks like im approaching it as a "given" probability.

Can someone guide me with this question?

Comment: where are the balls coming .. from ?

Comment: oops - was doing another question midst writing this. mb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes what you have is correct except that $P = \frac{B}{A}$ and not $\frac{A}{B}$. I am not sure why you think it is conditional probability. Instead of arrangements, you can simply look at it as selections of balls:

If the last two are pink then the first four are not pink.

So the desired probability is $ P = \displaystyle {4 \choose 4} / {6 \choose 4} = \frac{1}{15}$

Answer (score 3):

Alternative approach:

Probability of last two pink is the same as the probability of first two pink, which is

$\displaystyle \frac{2}{6} \times \frac{1}{5} = \frac{2}{30} = \frac{1}{15}.$

Answer (score 0):

There are ${6 \choose 2}=15$ ways to pick two positions for the pinks. So there is a $\frac{1}{15}$ probability that specifically the last two positions are chosen.